# Axiom of choice for subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm trying to solve following problem. Let $A_{i,j}$ be subsets of a set $X$ for $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that
$$\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A{i,j}=\bigcup_{(a_{i})}\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty A_{i,a_{i}},$$
where the second union is over all sequences $(a_i)^\infty_{i=0}$ of natural numbers. Do I need to use axiom of choice here?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question a few days ago. But I can't find the link.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need choice here, because the space of possible $j$s is already well-ordered. When you need to construct an $(a_i)$ sequence that verifies that some element is in your resulting set, you can just choose the *smallest* $j$ that works in each position.

If, on the other hand, the $j$s were drawn from an *arbitrary* index set rather than $\mathbb N$, you would need countable choice, though.